# Can anyone help me identify this bicycle frame?

Tags: frames, build, cannondale

I recently bought this frame from a gentleman who bought a closed bike shop and builds and sells bikes from his 10 or more sheds full of parts.  He teaches his church youth kids to build them as a way of staying out of trouble, I love that.  I acquired 90% of the parts I would need to put a bike together.  He was 100% sure this frame is a Cannondale frame (maybe 1987), but there is no serial number or marks at all that we can see. The fork reads Tange TF-R.  [image: actual frame]

[image: with the fork]
I need help from the experts.  Thank you.

Comment: I think teaching kids to stay out of trouble and trading bike frames with serial numbers removed is an odd combination.

Comment: It's probably from a bike.

Comment: If it is an old Cannondale, it would be aluminum... so see if a magnet sticks to it?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I managed to find a couple of similar frames on web search that suggest the 1987 [Vintage Cannodale](https://community.vintagecannondale.com/showcase/sr800.249/) identification could be correct. The really unique way the top-tube intersects the downtube before the head tube makes me think this is a very small frame. I would suggest it's a 1987 SR600 in 48cm